# Load Form from module into custom page template

Tags: forms, templates, drupal-7, admin, taxonomy

I have successfully added my own form (from the same module) into my custom template, but now I wish to load the taxonomy add term form (used by ubercart I think for product categories in the catalog vocab) into my template.

I have gotten this far with my module - filename `simpleadmin.module`

```php
/**
 * @file
 * A module to simplify the admin by replacing add/edit node pages
 */

function simpleadmin_menu() {
  $items['admin/products/categories/add'] = array(
    'title' => 'Add Category',
    'page callback' => 'simpleadmin_category_add',
    'access arguments' => array('access administration pages'),
    'menu_name' => 'menu-store',
  );
  return $items;
}

function simpleadmin_category_add() {
module_load_include('inc', 'taxonomy', 'taxonomy.admin');
$output = drupal_get_form('taxonomy_form_term');
return theme('simpleadmin_category_add', array('categoryform' => $output));
}

function simpleadmin_theme() {
  return array(
    'simpleadmin_category_add' => array(
      'template' => 'simpleadmin-template',
      'variables' => array('categoryform' => NULL),
      'render element' => 'form',
    ), 
  );
}
?>
```

And as for the theme file itself - filename `simpleadmin-template.tpl.php`, only very simple at the moment until I get the form to load into it:

```php
<div>
    This is the form template ABOVE the form
</div>


<?php
dpm($categoryform);
print drupal_render($categoryform);
?>

<div>
    This is the form template BELOW the form
</div>
```

Its telling me that it is

> Trying to get property of non-object in taxonomy_form_term()

and throwing up an error. Should I be using `node_add()` and passing the `nodetype`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To render a taxonomy term form, the function should be able to know the vocabulary to which it belongs to. Otherwise how would it know which form to show? I think this is the proper way to do it.

```
module_load_include('inc', 'taxonomy', 'taxonomy.admin');
if ($vocabulary = taxonomy_vocabulary_machine_name_load('vocabulary_name')) {
  $form = drupal_get_form('taxonomy_form_term', $vocabulary);
  return theme('simpleadmin_category_add', array('categoryform' => $form));
}
```

To redirect your form use hook_form_alter

```
function yourmodule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  //get your vocabulary id or use print_r or dpm for proper validation
    if($form_id == 'taxonomy_form_term' && $form['#vocabulary']['vid'] = '7' ){ 
  $form['#submit'][] = 'onix_sections_form_submit'; 
 }
}

function yourmodule_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
     $form_state['redirect'] = 'user';
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for helping with this. It does indeed load the correct form and adds a term to the vocabulary. It actually auto adds the name 'catalog' to the term name, but I'm sure I can modify the array before rendering it to fix that.

Comment: I don't suppose you know how to change the redirect page to the view i created to list the terms? Also, is there any way to change the status message from 'Created new term ...' to 'Created new category ...'?

Once again thanks for your time

Comment: To redirect the form and generally to modify how forms work you should use hook_form_alter. I'll add code to my answer so you know how. Everything else you need to modify is probably there too.

Comment: Ok so I have successfully modified the code to change the success message to say "New category ??? added" and the redirect works just fine too thanks to your help.

I'm kind of stuck with how this works when you are editing an existing taxonomy term, where is the form, how do i get the data from the currently editing term? this reply text box is short, should I put these in a new question and embed all of the code up to date?